# Wrapping Shapeless FieldType creation in a function

Tags: scala, shapeless

Is there a way to create an implicit class to provide a custom function to return a FieldType with the same type as the record-style singleton operator `->>`?

I'd like to do something like:

```
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

implicit class FieldMaker[S <: Symbol](val s: S) {
  def make[T](t: T) = s ->> t
}
```

so that the following two values have the same type:

```
val first  = 'test ->> Foo("bar")
val second = 'test make Foo("bar")
```

In previous attempts, I keep getting thwarted by the macros in `mkSingletonOps`. Any advice would be helpful!

**Update:**

The motivation for this stems from creating a DSL and trying to carefully control its syntax. The simplified example above skips past the purpose this implicit class is accomplishing in the DSL—specifically, applying a function to T returning a typeclass which is needed elsewhere in the DSL.

A more exemplary case would be:

```
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

def func(t: T): SomeTypeclass[T] = _  // elided

implicit class FieldMaker[S <: Symbol](val s: S) {
  def make[T](t: T) = s ->> func(t)
}
```

so that the following two values have the same type:

```
val first  = 'test ->> func(Foo("bar"))
val second = 'test make Foo("bar")
```

The expression assigned to `second` is the desired syntax for the DSL.

Comment: Why not use (or rename) `->>`?

Comment: I'm creating a DSL which does more than the example above and am trying to craft the syntax (of `make`) into something specific so the DSL looks as I intend. Using `->>` will work, but exposes that operator and the other work (not shown above). Renaming `->>` would help the syntax but would still require exposing the other work (which boils down to `f(Foo("bar"))`)

Comment: @MilesSabin does this mean that it's not possible in the current version of shapeless?

Comment: @Ryan finally I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018074/5249621) the way.

Comment: Spoiler alert: this isn't currently possible without reimplementing the macros in Shapeless. [See below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427400/wrapping-shapeless-fieldtype-creation-in-a-function#46018074)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably no.

```
  import shapeless.Witness
  import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
  import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

  implicit class FieldMaker[S <: Symbol](val s: S) {
    def make[T](t: T): FieldType[s.type, T] = s ->>[T] t
  }

  case class Foo(s: String)

  val first: FieldType[Witness.`'test`.T, Foo]  = 'test ->>[Foo] Foo("bar")
  val second: FieldType[fm.s.type, Foo] forSome { val fm: FieldMaker[Symbol] } = 
    'test make[Foo] Foo("bar")
  val third: FieldType[fm.s.type, Foo] forSome { val fm: FieldMaker[Witness.`'test`.T] } = 
    'test.narrow make[Foo] Foo("bar")
```

Type of `s ->>[T] t` is `FieldType[s.type, T]` and this doesn't depend on type parameter `S`.
But what is `s` in `s.type`? Before implicit conversion it's `'test` but after that it's just a field of an instance of `FieldMaker[S]` (instance, which exists only during implicit conversion) so we have existential type. And as soon as we have existential type we can't go back to `'test`.

This is how implicits work.

---

Actually finally I found the way to make `second` of the same type as `first` **(although it uses `.narrow`)**. I replaced implicit conversion with type class and implicit conversion.

```
  import shapeless.Witness
  import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
  import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
  import shapeless.tag.@@

  trait FieldMaker[S <: Symbol, T] {
    def make(t: T): FieldType[S, T]
  }

  object FieldMaker {
    implicit def mkFieldMaker[/*S <: Symbol*/U, T](implicit
                                                   witness: Witness.Aux[/*S*/Symbol @@ U]
                                                  ): FieldMaker[/*S*/Symbol @@ U, T] = {
      val name: /*S*/Symbol @@ U = witness.value
      new FieldMaker[/*S*/Symbol @@ U, T] {
        override def make(t: T): FieldType[/*S*/Symbol @@ U, T] =
          (name ->>[T] t).asInstanceOf[FieldType[/*S*/Symbol @@ U, T]]
      }
    }

    object op {
      implicit class FieldMakerOp[S <: Symbol](s: S) {
        def make[T](t: T)(implicit fm: FieldMaker[S, T]): FieldType[S, T] = fm.make(t)
      }
    }

  }

  case class Foo(s: String)

  val first: FieldType[Witness.`'test`.T, Foo]  = 'test ->>[Foo] Foo("bar")

  import FieldMaker.op._
  val second: FieldType[Witness.`'test`.T, Foo] = 'test.narrow make/*[Foo]*/ Foo("bar")
```

Comment: The syntax of the expression assigned to `second` is not the same as the example. The use of `.narrow` is the difference and also highlights the problem I've had with related attempts: the tagging of a Symbol's singleton-type is done via macros in the `singleton` object in shapeless. So the syntax of methods (e.g. `->>`) that can be used in a DSL like mine is limited to what exists in `trait SingletonOps` returned by the macro. I suggest you un-strikethrough your "probably no." statement and I'll accept this as the answer… with my thanks for the `.narrow` example.

Comment: I found your [Programming with Dependent Types in Scala](https://stepik.org/course/2294) course. It looks very interesting and seems relevant to recommend to anyone who has found this question/comment.

Comment: @Ryan Ok, I sligtly edited my answer. I'm glad you're interested in my course. Now I'm working on new one.